# How to implement a complete binary tree using C

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I have written a code in C to implement a complete binary tree but it's not working as intended. Please help me.

```
struct tree
{
    int data;
    struct tree *right,*left;
};
struct queue
{
    int front, rear;
    int size;
    struct tree* *array;
}; 
//q will be created in a createQueue  method
void insert(struct tree **root, int data, struct queue* q)
{
    struct tree *temp;
    if(*root==NULL)
    {
        *root=newNode(data);//newNode creates a new node
    }
    else if((*root)->left==NULL)
    {
        (*root)->left=newNode(data);
    }
    else if((*root)->right==NULL)
    {
        (*root)->right=newNode(data);
    }
    else
    {
        enqueue((*root)->left,q);
        enqueue((*root)->right,q);
        temp=dequeue(q);
        insert(&temp,data,q);
    }
}
void enqueue(struct tree *root, struct queue* q)
{
    if(q->front==q->size)
        return;
    if(q->front==-1)
    {
        q->front+=1;
    }
    q->rear+=1;
    q->array[q->rear]=root;
} 
struct tree* dequeue(struct queue* q)
{
    if(q->front==-1)
        return NULL;
    struct tree *temp;
    temp=q->array[q->front];
    q->front+=1;
    return temp;
}
```

Whenever I print the inorder, preorder and postorder traversal of the above tree i get the wrong output with an error saying stack smashing occured and the program terminates.

Edit:
The code for newNode is

```
struct tree* newNode(int data) 
{
    struct tree* temp;
    temp=(struct tree*)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
    temp->data=data;
    temp->right=NULL;
    temp->left=NULL;
    return temp;
}
```

The code for createQueue is:

```
struct queue* createQueue(int size)
{
  // fill in the code here
  struct queue* temp=(struct queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct queue));
  temp->size=size;
  temp->front=-1;
  temp->rear=-1;
  temp->array=(struct tree**)malloc(sizeof(struct tree));
  return temp;
}
```

I'm pretty sure the problem is arising in the insert or enqueue or dequeue functions because it happens only while inserting more than 3 nodes into the tree. But i can't understand why.

Comment: Why did you tag this question with c++? Did you try to debug your code?

Comment: Please include all relevant code causing the issue, preferably a [mcve]. And don’t tag c++ when the code is c

Comment: Quite possibly there's a problem with your `newNode` function.  Why don't you show us what it looks like?

Comment: We could also use your `main()`, and some sample input illustrating the problem.

Comment: What is "stack smashing?"

Comment: @JimMischel: It's a term used when broken code writes outside the bounds of a variable (usually an array) allocated on the stack, and the out of bounds writing modifies control information such as return addresses for function calls that are in progress.  It's a serious bug — and the basis of many security exploits.

Comment: How big is the queue you create?  Where in your code do you handle the wraparound when the front reaches the end of the array?  Typically a queue should be implemented with wrapround and you initialize it with `front = rear = 0;` and the queue is empty when `front == rear` (and it's full when `(front + 1) % size == rear`.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Interesting. I know what stack corruption is, of course. I've just not heard it called "stack smashing." Usually "corruption" or "overwrite." Are we sure it's not a stack overflow error that results from unbounded recursion?

Comment: [Smashing the Stack for Fun and Profit](http://phrack.org/issues/49/14.html) dates from 1996 — it is one of the first expositions on overwriting outside the bounds of the stack, @JimMischel.  That the term is used less often these days is pretty much undeniable, but it has historical precedence.  One of the compilers — or one of the options to some of the compilers (GCC, Clang) — detects egregious out of bounds writes and reports the problem as attempted stack smashing.  So, the term is still used.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Learn somethin' new every day. Thanks.